# mysql, is possible to get statistics about cpu usage and memory, after query or insert command?

Tags: mysql

On mysql I usually see time of query

```
select * from rooms;
+---------+---------------+----------+
| number  | room_name     | identify |
+---------+---------------+----------+
|       1 | myroom        |        1 |
|       2 | studio 1      |        4 |
|       3 | Dancefloor    |        7 |
+---------+---------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Is also possible to get cpu usage and memory from the mysql server?

Comment: CPU usage and memory of what? The timing data comes from the client, not the server. I'm not sure MySQL tracks CPU time per-query, and it certainly doesn't track memory since a lot of that is shared between queries.

Comment: From the server, I edit question now

Comment: Short answer: Nope. Long answer: MySQL exports a lot of data metrics and there's innumerable performance measurement tools, but none as simple as this.

Comment: Add as answer please, so I can vote and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's nothing more than the elapsed time. You can replicate it by storing the start time and subtracting it from the time when the query ends. Like this pseudo-code.

```
start = Time.now
do_the_query
end = Time.now

elapsed_time = end - start
```

Digging into the mysql source code, this is nothing more than the elapsed clock time.

Here's the relevant code in [client/mysql.cc](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/client/mysql.cc).

```
static ulong start_timer(void) {
#if defined(_WIN32)
  return clock();
#else
  struct tms tms_tmp;
  return times(&tms_tmp);
#endif
}

static void end_timer(ulong start_time, char *buff) {
  nice_time((double)(start_timer() - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, buff, true);
}

static void mysql_end_timer(ulong start_time, char *buff) {
  buff[0] = ' ';
  buff[1] = '(';
  end_timer(start_time, buff + 2);
  my_stpcpy(strend(buff), ")");
}
```

```
static int com_go(String *buffer, char *line MY_ATTRIBUTE((unused))) {
  ...

  char time_buff[52 + 3 + 1]; /* time max + space&parens + NUL */

  ...

  timer = start_timer();
  executing_query = true;
  error = mysql_real_query_for_lazy(buffer->ptr(), buffer->length());

  ...

    if (verbose >= 3 || !opt_silent)
      mysql_end_timer(timer, time_buff);
    else
      time_buff[0] = '\0';
```

If you don't read C...

1. `timer = start_timer();` gets the current time from `times`.
2. `mysql_real_query_for_lazy` runs the query.
3. `mysql_end_timer(timer, time_buff)` subtracts the current time from the start time and displays it.